# How can I stop the textarea from disappearing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form that adds comment from the user:

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment_box" placeholder="Share your thoughts" cols="175" rows="9"></textarea>     

<input type="button" name="add_comment" id="add_comment_button" value="Add comment" 
 onclick="add_comment_js('comment_form','{$type}')">
```

Once I click on the button "Add comment" the textarea disappears (I think using jquery), no css files included.

A big [functions.js](http://tedxtube.com/js/functions.js) file is linked also, I suspect this method inside the javascript file has to do with the disappearance:

```
  function add_comment_js(form_id,type)
  {
    var formObjectData = $('#'+form_id).serialize()+'&mode=add_comment';

    $.post(page,formObjectData,
    function(data)
    {
        if(!data)
            alert("No data");
        else
        {
            if(data.cid)
            {
                get_the_comment(data.cid,"#latest_comment_container");
                $("#"+form_id).slideUp();
            }
        }
    },'json');
}
```

Why is the textarea hiding after I post the comment? What's wrong?

Comment: Comment out functions.js temporarily and see if your theory is correct.

Comment: post the code for the complete form, probably .slideUp() is messing up

Comment: Whatever JSON object you are getting from your $.post function, the "cid" key is set and therefore the .slideUp() method is being called on the text box.  Check to make sure that data.cid is in fact set (you might need to try "data.cid!==undefined")

Comment: @Nicolas, when I do that, the comment won't be posted when I press the button and thus I can't test it.

Comment: `$("#"+form_id).slideUp();` makes it slide up, out of view. You should be able to comment out that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line form your code

```
$("#"+form_id).slideUp();
```

final result should look :

```
function add_comment_js(form_id,type)
{
    var formObjectData = $('#'+form_id).serialize()+'&mode=add_comment';

    $.post(page,formObjectData,
    function(data)
    {
        if(!data)
            alert("No data");
        else
        {
            if(data.cid)
            {
                get_the_comment(data.cid,"#latest_comment_container");
            }
        }
    },'json');
}
```

Comment: I downvoted because Brent was first and deserved the acceptance. This kid just stole his solution and posted the full code block.

Comment: @Nicolas yeah :) anyway didn't saw Brent's post till i've submited mine

Answer (score 2):

`$("#"+form_id).slideUp();` is hiding the form when this function runs. Remove that line and the textarea should persist. Slideup "Hides the matched elements with a sliding motion." Here's the [jQuery API reference](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) for that function.